# Powershell Enums in different languages - Localized Enums?

Tags: powershell, enums, internationalization, multilingual, powershell-5.0

I need to write some date functions in Powershell for a current project, and a couple of those require the name of a day as `param`. Since I am writing this for an English speaking site, I will allow as valid inputs:

- `Mon`, `Tue`, `Wed`, `Thu`, `Fri`, `Sat`, `Sun`
- `Monday`, `Tuesday`, `Wednesday`, `Thursday`, `Friday`, `Saturday`, `Sunday`
- `Mo`, `Tu`, `We`, `Th`, `Fr`, `Sa`, `Su`

I want to put some of these into my toolkit, so I would like to make the script work in any language. I know how to use `Import-LocalizedData` for all my help texts and prompts, those are pretty easy.

Is there a way to have localized enums? Or is the better way to create enums in the most common languages and switch them based on the OS's current locale at runtime?